# Optimization Python Loops for Algorithm

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, performance, for-loop, data-structures

Hi Working on an algorithm with some complicated functions, simplified things and pasted below, for one case of many iterations I have to complete. Have explanation below and code example, it is done with for loops and is very slow as my actual data has very large arrays and recursion.

Looking for better way to do this part much faster. What structures are faster, what is more a more "pythonic" approach. Please help.

Have to turn this array:

Arr=[21,20,19,18,17,16,15,0,0,0,0,0,0]

Into this:

[21, 20, 19.3, 18.3, 17.3, 16.3, 15.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

**According to following 5 steps in the algorithm:**

1.find first non-zero and index it

2.find close to "terminal value" with a greater than a condition.

3.In this case used >17 as proxy for that condition

4.Find the actual "terminal value", which requires one test condition (In this case used Odd as a proxy for that condition)
-if it passes: It is the actual "terminal value" at k
-if it fails then "terminal value" is in the one preceeding it k-1

5.Then replace the the values of the array by the weighted (70/30) average of values from the array, from the Index until the "terminal value" k, must calculate average before replacing to not disturb next average calculation

Edit: Someone asked for a walkthrough-
step 1: first non-zero is 15 with index 6
Step 2/3: close to terminal looking for > 17, which is 18 with index 3. note in real data set will only know if my terminal value is the one from the test or the next one. which is what is performed next.
Step 4: check if 18 is odd -> Falis so must be next one. So terminal value is 19 with index 2.
Step 5: Now I calc weighted averages of the original array between the first non-zero element and the terminal value, not recursively, and keeping the size of the array the same. Index 6 (first non-zero) value 15 gets replaced with 0.7*15 + 0.3*16 = 15.3 , Index 5 value 16 gets replaced with 0.7*16 + 0.3*17= 16.3, Index 4 value 17 gets replaced with 0.7*17 + 0.3*18 = 17.3, Index 3 value 18 gets replaced with 0.7*18 + 0.3*19 = 18.3, Index 2 (terminal) value 15 gets replaced with 0.7*19 + 0.3*20 = 19.3. End.

```
n=12
Arr=[21,20,19,18,17,16,15,0,0,0,0,0,0]    

   

#find first non-zero and index it
for i in range(n,-1,-1):
    if Arr[i]>0:
        Index=i
        break    

#find close to "terminal value" with a greater than a condition. 
#In this case used >17 as proxy for that condition
for i in range(Index,-1,-1):     
    if Arr[i]>17:
        Close=i
        break

#Find the actual "terminal value", which requires one test condition 
#if it passes: It is the actual "terminal value" at k
#if it fails then "terminal value" is in the one preceeding it k-1
#In this case used Odd as a proxy for that condition
#Then replace the the values of the array by the weighted (70/30) average of values from the array
#from the Index until the "terminal value" k
#must calculate average before replacing
        
if Arr[Close] %2 != 0 :
    k=Close 
else: 
    k= Close -1

for i in range(Index,k-1,-1):
   Arr[i]=.7*Arr[i]+.3*Arr[i-1]
```

Comment: I don't understand those five steps?? Why do you add .3 to some numbers but not the others? What are you trying to do?

Comment: In step 1, what does index it mean?  In step 2/3 what does find close to terminal value mean?   In step 4 what does find terminal value mean?  In step 5 what do you mean by weighted average 70/30 70 of what 30 of what?  also in which array are you replacing values.  What doe it mean from index until terminal value?   Could you walk thru your example and show the operations for each step?

Comment: If the elements are sorted, as in the example, you can find the first two positions with a binary search. You still adjust one with the condition but that is constant time. Then you have log running time for finding the indexes and linear for the updates. For the updates you can’t go faster, of course, but there might be solutions for the search that is faster, depending on the data.

Comment: Itproh66 -> Instep 1: Index it means the index of the first non-zero element.

Comment: Itproh66 -> In step2/3 In my more complex rel world problem, my terminal value will be the result of a computation, and according to a test will be that one, or the next one. So close to terminal may be the terminal, and the test lets me know if I need that one or the next one. 

Itproh66 -> In step 5 a weighted average (70/30)  is simply 0.7 * Val[i] + >0.3 val[i+1]; of course in my real world problem it is more sophisticated.

Itproh66 -> "Replacing" means performing a calculation like the weighted average for all values between the first non-zero element and the terminal value.

Comment: Lastly, length of the array remains intact, and the calculation of one average does not change the next average.

Comment: Itproh66, will "walk through" to body of question.

Comment: Stef, what I am trying to do is generate a more efficient algorithm to solve a real world problem. But have abstracted the complex details of the problem with simple ones as illustrated as they are the only thing required for the optional algorithm. So I provided essentially an analogue for my real problem and am asking for a way to optimize this.